# Chrome browser frozen from scam tab. How to fix?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I got an ad popup in a new tab in the Chrome broswer from visiting a site & now that tab ad won't close or let me use Chrome.

Tried force stopping & clearing cache but Chrome is still frozen. Tried restarting phone. No change. See the photo for the tab that won't close.  It's the "critical..." one that has frozen Chrome. Can't close any tabs at all too. Any suggestions? Also,  Malwarebytes' scan result = nothing.

[image]

Comment: how bout turning wi fi and data off and trying to open Chrome again? Will it still be like this?

Comment: You didn't mention clearing data of Chrome app from Settings app. Are you avoiding it for some reason? That would definitely solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could always uninstall chrome, and then reinstall. That's assuming you don't have any bookmarks you care about.

Comment: If the app was preinstalled in your system you can 'uninstall updates' and force stop Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a warranty on your phone anymore, you can root it and then uninstall 'preinstalled apps'.

Comment: Can you please provide instructions for both of them?

Comment: That depends a lot on the phone. But there's an app - [One Click Root](https://www.oneclickroot.com/)- that worked fine for two of my phones (LG G3 and Samsung Galaxy A5 2017). After you root your phone, install System App Remover, you can find it on play store or on One Click Root page at [Root Apps](https://www.oneclickroot.com/top-root-apps/). The through that app you can remove preinstalled apps from your Android device.
ADVICE: When rooting your phone, search and read carefully and make sure it's alright to root it. Nobody wants to brick their phone.

Answer (score 0):

Just wipe user data, related to browser (Settings => Apps). No need for reinstall, wiping data+cache is the important step!